# Can I protect 3 branch circuits with a GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have 4 sets of wires coming into one outlet. 4 black 4 whites and 4 ground.  1 set is hot when power is on, all the rest are not.  I need to switch the outlet to a gfi outlet.  Is this even safe?

Comment: Note that this is all on the same branch circuit - it's just devices being fed from the outlet/GFCI in question.

Comment: It is safe (if done correctly), and no different than using a GFCI breaker (which protects the entire circuit).

Answer (score 3):

This is easy -- pigtail all the black (hot) wires together except for the one that's actually hot, and do the same with the white (neutral) wires.  Then, connect the hot black/white to the corresponding LINE terminals on the GFCI, and the pigtail black/white to the matching LOAD terminals on the GFCI.  Finally, pigtail *all* the grounds together and connect them to the GFCI's ground screw.

(If you don't want the rest of the circuit GFCI protected, leave a comment or edit your question.)